# Sending an email

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger

Consider this scenario, I have two fields and a save button and when I click on the save button I must be able to send an email of the two field values . Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
<apex:page standardcontroller=newcontroller>

<apex:inputField value="{!newcontroller__c.Picklist1__c}
<apex:inputField value="{!newcontroller__c.Picklist2__c}

<apex:commandbutton action={!Save} value="Save"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a [Workflow Rule](http://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wfrules.htm&language=en_US) and specify the rule criteria for it however you see fit.  For example, if you want it to execute every time one of your records is saved then set the Rule Criteria to *true* and the Evaluation Criteria to *Evaluate the rule when a record is created, and every time it’s edited*.

Once you have the rule created you can then add an [Email Alert Workflow Action to it](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_alerts.htm&language=en_US).  You configure your Email Alert to have an Email Template.  In that Email Template you can refer to those two fields using merge fields.

```
 Val1: {!YourObject__c.Picklist1__c}
 Val2: {!YourObject__c.Picklist2__c}
```

The power of this is that there is no code involved, so it is maintainable by a non coder.

Clicks not code. ;)

Comment: High five for declarative solution!